# Is there a way to underline a character in string in a JLabel?

Tags: java, string, character, underline

I just want to underline a character in a string in my JLabel, how can I do that, I've been searching the web for a simple way of doing it in Java but I can't find anything. For example I have a text "Modify" in a JLabel and I just want to underline "M" in Modify how do I do that? Thanks in advance.

Underline the character in my string in a JLabel.

Comment: Why do you want to underline "M"? To add a keyboard shortcut, or just to have it underlined for visual purposes?

Comment: Keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML in your JLabel text -

```
label.setText("<html><u>M</u>odify</html>");
```

Comment: Is that syntax applicable to a swing program?

Comment: Yes - you can read more about it here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try it.